# Access label in a cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made a custom cell in a table view. There are some buttons and labels in a cell. I'm making a delegate method and call it on the action of the button. The button is also in a cell. Now i'm trying that whenever user press button the label text should increment by one. I'm trying to access the cell label outside the cellForRow delegate method but fail. How can i get the label in a cell outside the cellForRow delegate method in my button action? I have tried some code,
this is in my cell class,

```
protocol cartDelegate {
func addTapped()
func minusTapped()
}

var delegate : cartDelegate?
 @IBAction func addBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    delegate?.addTapped()
}

@IBAction func minusBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    delegate?.minusTapped()
}
```

This is in my view controller class,

```
extension CartViewController : cartDelegate{

func addTapped() {

    total += 1
    print(total)

}

func minusTapped() {
    total -= 1
    print(total)
}
```

}
 this is cellForRow method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CartTableViewCell

    cell.dishTitleLbl.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.priceLbl.text = priceArray[indexPath.row]
    price = Int(cell.priceLbl.text!)!
    print(price)
    cell.dishDetailLbl.text = "MANGO,Apple,Orange"
    print(cell.dishDetailLbl.text)
    total = Int(cell.totalLbl.text!)!

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

I want to access priceLbl in my addTapped and minusTapped functions.

Comment: what you want is update the pricelable which is inside the cell so everytime user precess the button you have to update the cell, so create delegate by passing the label or button, you can use tag property to get cell index and update that cell.
but in your cellForRowAt you are setting priceArray[indext.row] so what you actually need to do is update the priceArray[index.row] + 1 when user press on the button. you can update single row using tableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade). 
#update your delegate method and logic for updating price array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your protocol to pass the cell:

```
protocol cartDelegate {
func addTappedInCell(_ cell: CartTableViewCell)
func minusTappedInCell(_ cell: CartTableViewCell)
}
```

Change your IBActions to pass the cell:

```
@IBAction func addBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.addTappedInCell(self)
}

@IBAction func minusBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.minusTappedInCell(self)
}
```

And then your delegate can do whatever it wants to the cell.

Comment: perfect one got it. Thanks a lot. @ghostatron

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access the `label` inside of `CartViewController` but outside of `cellForRowAt` you have to be able to access a particular cell. To achieve that, since you are dynamically dequeueing reusable cells, you will need an `indexPath` of that cell and then you can ask the `tableView` to give you the cell:

```
// I will here assume it is a third cell in first section of the tableView
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
// ask the tableView to give me that cell
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell
// and finally access the `priceLbl`
cell.priceLbl.text = priceArray[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thank you Milan. I have been looking for this answer fro days. I appreciate it! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It should be something as simple as:
`self.priceLbl.text = "count = \(total)"`

Comment: it is showing me this error Value of type 'CartViewController' has no member 'priceLbl'.